# How can I get access to a component that is a child route from the parent component?

Tags: angular

I have something like this in my routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'master', 
    component: MasterComponent, 
    children: [
      {
        path: 'first',
        component: FirstComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'second',
        component: SecondComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The idea is that when I go to the address `http://site/master/*option*` it will render the master component plus whichever component I am putting in `*option*`.

The master component has a `<router-outlet>` inside of it, and in there it will render the "option" I'm navigating to. That is working perfectly, and rendering just fine. However, what I want to do now is from Master find a value inside the option component I navigated to. An example is a title I will display in Master which varies depending on the "option" component I'm navigating to. Is there any way I can achieve this? Or maybe there's a better way to do it.

I was trying to use `ViewChild` or `ViewChildren` but both require that you define the type of the Component, and since the component will not always be the same, it's not viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with 2 method

###### Method #1

Use `activate` event of router outlet

```html
<!-- master.component.html -->
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

```js
//master.component.ts
onActivate(componentRef){
  console.log(componentRef.title); //access methods and properties of current loaded component
}
```

###### Method #2

Add title variable in service and change it in child component

```js
//master.service.ts
title = '';

changeTitle(title) {
 this.title = title;
}
```

```js
//first.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.masterService.changeTitle('First');
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!